# Spark Core's API returns HTTPS 400 error

Tags: python, http, https

I'm trying to make HTTPS requests to Spark's Cloud API. I am using the following code with the httplib library

```
import httplib
spark = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.spark.io")
spark.request("GET", "/v1/devices")
response = spark.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
```

According to the Spark [API documentation](http://docs.spark.io/api/), this should work. But instead, I get 400 Bad Request. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spark Cloud uses traditional HTTP response codes to provide feedback from the Core regarding the validity of the request and its success or failure.

The reason you getting the 400 error is because you do not post the `access token` and `id` as in the example from the documentation below:

```
POST /v1/devices

# EXAMPLE REQUEST
curl https://api.spark.io/v1/devices \
     -d access_token=1234 \
     -d id=0123456789abcdef01234567
```

This can easily be solved by using this fix:

```
import httplib
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept": "text/plain"}
params = {"access_token": "1234", "id": "0123456789abcdef01234567"}
spark = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.spark.io")
spark.request("GET", "/v1/devices", params, headers)
response = spark.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
```

The params should be your `access token` and `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Forgot to read the response content ?

```
>>> import httplib
>>> spark = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.spark.io")
>>> spark.request("GET", "/v1/devices")
>>> response = spark.getresponse()
>>> print response.status, response.reason
400 Bad Request
>>> response.read()
'{\n  "error": "invalid_request",\n  "error_description": "The access token was not found"\n}'
>>>
```

FWIW you could have found out by yourself just accessing the url in your browser...